# Reshape, recombine row with column

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset like this:

```
Block   Vector
blk_-1  0.0 2 3, 0.5 3 8, 0.7 33 5
blk_-2  1.0 4 1, 2.0 2 4
blk_-3  0.0 0 0, 6.0 0 7
blk_-4  8.0 3 0, 7.0 5 8
blk_-5  9.0 0 5, 5.0 0 2, 5.2 3 2, 5.9 5 3

dat = {'Block': ['blk_-1', 'blk_-2', 'blk_-3', 'blk_-4',  'blk_-5'],\
        'Vector': ['0.0 2 3, 0.5 3 8, 0.7 33 5',\
                   '1.0 4 1, 2.0 2 4',\
                   '0.0 0 0, 6.0 0 7',\
                   '8.0 3 0, 7.0 5 8',\
                  '9.0 0 5, 5.0 0 2, 5.2 3 2, 5.9 5 3']
       }
```

I want to get:

```
Block   Vector

blk_-1   0.0 2 3

blk_-1   0.5 3 8

blk_-1   0.7 33 5

blk_-2   1.0 4 1

blk_-2   2.0 2 4

blk_-3   0.0 0 0

blk_-3   6.0 0 7

blk_-4   8.0 3 0

blk_-4   7.0 5 8

blk_-5   9.0 0 5

blk_-5   5.0 0 2

blk_-5   5.2 3 2    

blk_-5   5.9 5 3
```

Try:

```
df['Vector'] = df['Vector'].apply(lambda x : list(map(str, x.split(','))))
```

```
df.Vector.apply(pd.Series) \
    .merge(df, left_index = True, right_index = True) \
    .drop(["Vector"], axis = 1)
```

Get:

```
    0   1   2   3                   Block
0   0.0 2 3 0.5 3 8 0.7 33 5    NaN blk_-1
1   1.0 4 1 2.0 2 4 NaN NaN         blk_-2
2   0.0 0 0 6.0 0 7 NaN NaN         blk_-3
3   8.0 3 0 7.0 5 8 NaN NaN         blk_-4
4   9.0 0 5 5.0 0 2 5.2 3 2 5.9 5 3         blk_-5
```

Actually
Stuck at this moment. Waiting for your ideas and comments :)

Comment: I see changed accepted answer, it is OK, but better is add `.reset_index(drop=True)` for default index values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for pandas 0.25+ - [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column and assign back with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and last for default index add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

df = df.assign(Vector=df['Vector'].str.split(',')).explode('Vector').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     Block     Vector
0   blk_-1    0.0 2 3
1   blk_-1    0.5 3 8
2   blk_-1   0.7 33 5
3   blk_-2    1.0 4 1
4   blk_-2    2.0 2 4
5   blk_-3    0.0 0 0
6   blk_-3    6.0 0 7
7   blk_-4    8.0 3 0
8   blk_-4    7.0 5 8
9   blk_-5    9.0 0 5
10  blk_-5    5.0 0 2
11  blk_-5    5.2 3 2
12  blk_-5    5.9 5 3
```

Version for oldier pandas versions - use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) + [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) for new `Series` and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = (df.join(df.pop('Vector')
                .str.split(',',expand=True)
                .stack()
                .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                .rename('Vector')).reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
     Block     Vector
0   blk_-1    0.0 2 3
1   blk_-1    0.5 3 8
2   blk_-1   0.7 33 5
3   blk_-2    1.0 4 1
4   blk_-2    2.0 2 4
5   blk_-3    0.0 0 0
6   blk_-3    6.0 0 7
7   blk_-4    8.0 3 0
8   blk_-4    7.0 5 8
9   blk_-5    9.0 0 5
10  blk_-5    5.0 0 2
11  blk_-5    5.2 3 2
12  blk_-5    5.9 5 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use split, explode and join.

```
df[['Block']].join(df.Vector.str.split(',').explode())

    Block   Vector
0   blk_-1  0.0 2 3
0   blk_-1  0.5 3 8
0   blk_-1  0.7 33 5
1   blk_-2  1.0 4 1
1   blk_-2  2.0 2 4
2   blk_-3  0.0 0 0
2   blk_-3  6.0 0 7
3   blk_-4  8.0 3 0
3   blk_-4  7.0 5 8
4   blk_-5  9.0 0 5
4   blk_-5  5.0 0 2
4   blk_-5  5.2 3 2
4   blk_-5  5.9 5 3
```

Comment: Better is avoid duplicated index values in pandas, because some function like `reindex` failed...

Answer (score 1):

For lower than version `.25`:

```
final=df.merge(df['Vector'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().reset_index(0,name='Vector'),
left_index=True,right_on='level_0',suffixes=('_x','')).drop(['level_0','Vector_x'],1)
print(final)
```

---

```
    Block     Vector
0  blk_-1    0.0 2 3
1  blk_-1    0.5 3 8
2  blk_-1   0.7 33 5
0  blk_-2    1.0 4 1
1  blk_-2    2.0 2 4
0  blk_-3    0.0 0 0
1  blk_-3    6.0 0 7
0  blk_-4    8.0 3 0
1  blk_-4    7.0 5 8
0  blk_-5    9.0 0 5
1  blk_-5    5.0 0 2
2  blk_-5    5.2 3 2
3  blk_-5    5.9 5 3
```